# Do I need to fsync before deleting file?

Tags: c, linux, io, buffer, synchronized

The question is related with implementing file copy in linux:
1. Create a new file
2. Copying data to this file
3. If user want to stop before copying finished, this new file should be deleted

Do I need to call fsync before closing this file and then unlink it?
Because closing file will not do fsync, does unlink will not delete the file until all dirty data of this file finished written back to disc?
I want to make sure the file is really unlinked at the time unlink() command returned.

Comment: Why? If you're going to delete it, why do you care whether the last write gets to the disk or not?

Comment: Please read the description more carefully.  I care because I need to make sure the file is finished deleted when unlink() command returned.

Answer (score 0):

If user stops it before copying, Simply call fsync() and unlink(). It will sync data in to disk and deletes your file

Comment: Why bother with fsync? If the data is going to be deleted, is ensuring a sync (where it wouldn't otherwise be used) useful/needed?

Comment: I fear that after calling unlink(), it is still linked because it waits the buffer to be flushed.

@Chinna:Closing file does not guarantee flushing I/O buffers to disc.
From manual of close():
"A successful close does not guarantee that the data has been successfully saved to disk, as the kernel defers writes. It is not common for a file system to flush the buffers when the stream is closed. If you need to be sure that the data is physically stored use fsync(2). (It will depend on the disk hardware at this point.)"

Comment: @dragon135 look this page http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/unlink.html. You are good to go when _unlink_ returns success.

Comment: @VoidPointer  there is no mention about cache. Also "If one or more processes have the file open when the last link is removed, the link shall be removed before unlink() returns, but the removal of the file contents shall be postponed until all references to the file are closed" means unlink() returns success but actually the file is still not removed. I want to make sure the file is really unlinked at the time unlink() command returned.
I guess the safe way is to call fsync() then close() then unlink().

Comment: @dragon135 if am not wrong, the file cant be referred by anybody after your unlink() call. The process who has opened it already can continue to access. When they close it, the file will be automatically removed from file-system. But note, you are the one who created it just moments back - no chance for others to touch it. Even when others have opened it, you cant do anything with their access, I guess..

Comment: @VoidPointer the problem is there is a lot of while(user not stop) { write(32KB) to the file; } going on to the file before user choose to stop, so after I close the file it actually still continue finishing writing cache to the disc. So when I call unlink() after close() I think the file does not immediately unlinked, it wait the cache flush to disc finished first.

Comment: Why do we need to call fsync first? Wouldn't unlink look at whether there are no links left, regardless of whether these links have actually been flushed to disk or not? So I don't see why you would need an fsync beforehand. But please someone correct me if my understanding is incorrect. Also, is it not the case that you need an fsync after the unlink to ensure the file doesn't come back during a potential crash?